# A question about intersection of center and commutator subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group such that $G'\cap Z(G)\neq 1$. Suppose also that $G'$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group; $G'\nleq Z(G)  $; $(G/Z(G))'$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G/Z(G)$.
Can we deduce that  $(G/Z(G))'\cap Z(G/Z(G))\neq 1$?

Comment: (1) The center of a group is Z(G), capital "z"; (2) Background, insights...about this question?

Comment: I have to prove an equivalent assert of "$G$ is also not abelian, but every proper subgroup of $G$ is abelian". At some point in the proof we assume by contradiction $G'\cap  Z(G)\neq 1$. Immediately he deduce $ (G/Z(G))′∩Z(G/Z(G))≠1$. Other than the previously results we have also that: The center of $G$ coincide with the Frattini subgroup of $G$; $G$ is finite; $G=G'Z(G)C$ where $C$ is a cyclic subgroup.

Comment: "He" is Reynolds Bear, who generally explicit all, every step.

Comment: This smells like character theory, is this for a representation theory course?

Comment: Is G' a subgroup of G

Comment: No... The argument is "Topics in Finite Groups: Minimal Classes"

Comment: $G'$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$

Comment: Another observation: if you have that $Z(G)=\Phi(G)$, then $G$ can't be nilpotent, or we'd have $(G/Z(G))'=1$.

Comment: Neat question though,! I would find it very interesting to hear an answer to "When does $G'\cap Z(G))\not= 1$ imply that $(G/Z(G))'\cap Z(G/Z(G))'\not= 1$?"

Answer (score 3):

No, we can't.  Minimal counterexample: $G=\text{SmallGroup}(96,197)$.

In here, $G'\cong  \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $Z(G)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

$G/Z(G)\cong\text{SmallGroup}(48,49)$, and $(G/Z(G))'\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G/Z(G)$. We have that $Z(G/Z(G))\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ as well, but the two intersect trivially.

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your answer. Here's my real  problem  
[1](http://v3rgil.altervista.org/Video/1.jpg)  
[2](http://v3rgil.altervista.org/Video/2.jpg)  
[3](http://v3rgil.altervista.org/Video/3.jpg)  
[4](http://v3rgil.altervista.org/Video/4.jpg)  
[5](http://v3rgil.altervista.org/Video/5.jpg)  
[6](http://v3rgil.altervista.org/Video/6.jpg)  
[7](http://v3rgil.altervista.org/Video/7.jpg)  .
My question refers to the last picture.
I obviously miss a condition that runs everything...
Finding it would provide an answer also to your question above (at least in some particular case).